# How to update all other values on a form every time another value changes in react native

Tags: react-native, publish-subscribe, android-livedata

I'm trying to write a form that acts like an Excel sheet. So, when one value changes, I want any other value that depends on it to change. In android I would use live data (subscriber pattern).

But, I'm writing this app in React Native and I have a lot of different values. What is the most EFFICIENT way to do this?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS